# Have Bigger Thumbnail for YouTube Video on Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I'm making a related post based on this tutorial: https://helplogger.blogspot.co.id/2016/09/new-related-posts-widget-for-blogger.html

The only issue is, the image rendered from YouTube video is too small. I checked the source and this what I have: .../blablabla/default.jpg. Is there a way to replace the default.jpg to maxresdefault? I need the thumbnail to be in hi-res.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the widget code, you will have to add an extra `replace` directive to the `media$thumbnail` property -

```
... ?c[r].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg", "/maxresdefault.jpg").replace(/\/s[0-9]+(\-c)?/,"/"+d.thumbnailSize):d.defaultThumb ...
```